# change plugin shortcode function

Tags: plugins, shortcode

i use a [plugin](http://www.broobe.com/wordpress-plugins/wp-jquery-timelinr/) that containing this code and i want to change the css and js and template.php location to be located in my template directory instead of plugin without editing the plugin files

```
public function shortcode($atts, $content = NULL) {

    global $post, $wpdb;

    STATIC $i = 1;



    $timelinr_options = get_option('timelinr_general_options');

    $desing_options = get_option('timelinr_desing_options');

    $pairs = array(

            'orientation' => $timelinr_options['orientation'],

            'startat' => intval($timelinr_options['startat']),

            'arrowkeys' => $timelinr_options['arrowkeys'],

            'autoplay' => $timelinr_options['autoplay'],

            'autoplaydirection' => $timelinr_options['autoplaydirection'],

            'autoplaypause' => $timelinr_options['autoplaypause'],

            'order' => $timelinr_options['order'],

            'containerdiv' => 'timelinr-'.$i,

            'category' => '',

            'dateformat' => $desing_options['dateformat'],

    );

    $atts = shortcode_atts($pairs, $atts );



    if ( strcmp ( $atts['orientation'] , 'horizontal' ) == 0){

        wp_enqueue_style('timelinr-style', JQTL_BASE_URL . '/assets/css/style.css', '', JQTL_CURRENT_VERSION );

    } elseif ( strcmp ( $atts['orientation'] , 'vertical' ) == 0) {

        wp_enqueue_style('timelinr-style_v', JQTL_BASE_URL . '/assets/css/style_v.css', '', JQTL_CURRENT_VERSION );

    }



    ob_start();

    include (JQTL_BASE_PATH . '/includes/template.php');

    $out = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();



    $i++;

    return $out;

}
```

Comment: Which plugin are you referring to?

Comment: http://www.broobe.com/wordpress-plugins/wp-jquery-timelinr/

Comment: If you want to do it, just do it; what stops you?. But the changes will be lost on plugin updates because, as I see in the code you posted, the plugin doesn't support css/js/template overriding. You should contact with the plugin developer to ask him about allowing that kind of customization or fork the plugin and continue the developing at your own. There is nothing we can do. Also, please note that [support/questions about for third party plugins are off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can override the shortcode like this :

```
add_action("init", function () {


    remove_shortcode("timelinr");

    add_shortcode("timelinr", function ($atts, $content) {

        // call the shortcode of jqueryTimelinrLoad
        $result = $GLOBALS["jqueryTimelinrLoad"]->shortcode($atts, $content);

        // dequeue style
        wp_dequeue_style("timelinr-style");

        // enqueue your style
        wp_enqueue_style("timelinr-style2", "new.css");

        // result of the shortcode
        return $result;
    });

});
```

Comment: i add it to function.php but css link not replaced

Comment: i made a misspelling and the new CSS need a new name. I corrected the code

Comment: it remove the shortcode but add nothing

Comment: the 2nd edition of the code work with my test - check your HTML result

Comment: it works now thx alot