# Modify Plugin shortcode function code

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I've got this shortcode from the Fusion Builder plugin that I want to modify. To avoid my changes being overwritten by plugin updates, I want to place the code elsewhere so it won't be a nightmare to maintain. But how can I do that?

This is the original code:
https://codeshare.io/29OmxM

And this is with my changes:
https://codeshare.io/5MNgWR

What's changed is:

- line 130: added $billet_website
- line 153: replaced get_the_permalink()
- line 173: replaced get_the_permalink()

*Mads*

Comment: See accepted of this question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/192811/change-plugin-shortcode-function  you can override shortcode.

Comment: Perfect Arsalan! But I don't understand what goes in the middel. Do I paste the entire code again or can I simply use str_replace ? https://codeshare.io/5RblzL

Comment: you should try the method defined, why you pasted the answer here?

Comment: Don't know why. Then I'm not sure I understand at all :/

Comment: what changes you really want to do?

Comment: See accepted answer of [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/192811/change-plugin-shortcode-function). you can override plugin shortcode. place the code in your **functions.php** & do the changes you want to.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I've edited my question above to explain